# Why the difference of integral on subsets are bounded with these two conditions?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Suppose $\{f_n\}\subset L^+$, $f_n\to f$ pointwise, and $\int f = \lim \int f_n<\infty$. Then $\int_E f=\lim \int_E f_n$ for all $E$ measurable.

I found it difficult to combine the two assumptions together. The obvious approach is that we need to bound $|\int_Ef-\int_Ef_n|$. I found that the pointwise convergence *alone* is not sufficient to bound it because we know that uniform convergence is needed to bound difference of integral. And the convergence of integral on the entire set alone can't bound it either, since we don't have monotonicity here, thus $|\int_Ef-\int_Ef_n|$ is not necessarily less than $|\int f-\int f_n|$. But it seems that somehow if these two conditions are both given, then it must be the case described by the theorem. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

This is an exercise on [Fatou's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma). Informally stated, the lemma says that taking the pointwise limit of nonnegative functions cannot create mass (i.e., integral) out of nothing, though it may destroy it.

You are told that there is no loss of mass on the whole domain of integration. Could there be a loss on the set $E$? No, because it would have to be offset by gain on the complement $ E^c$, and such a gain is prohibited by Fatou's lemma.

Stated in precise terms: applying Fatou's lemma on  $E^c$, we find that 
$$\int_{E^c } f \le \liminf \int_{E^c} f_n \tag{1}$$
Subtracting* inequality (1) from the given equality
$$\int  f = \lim \int  f_n \tag{2}$$
we obtain 
$$   \int_{E  } f \ge \limsup   \int_{E } f_n \tag{3}$$
On the other hand, Fatou's lemma on $E$ says
$$\int_{E  } f \le \liminf \int_{E } f_n \tag{4}$$
From (3) and (4) the conclusion follows.

---

(*) This is where we need to know that both sides of (2) are finite. Otherwise $\infty-\infty$ could happen.